# How would I get the number of repositories for each user of an array?

Tags: javascript, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to get the number of respositories of a few users using GitHub’s v4 API. In their explorer I found that I can query `user(login: String!)` however, that is only one users repositories count that I can see. Is it possible to loop though a list of users and get their each one of their repository counts using GitHub’s v4 API?

Comment: You can also find an issue about this too. https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to add more `user` query to your request and build the graphql query programmatically looping through the user list. In the graphql explorer it would be something like this :

```json
{
  torvalds: user(login: "torvalds") {
    repositories() {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  nelenkov: user(login: "nelenkov") {
    repositories() {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  evilsocket: user(login: "evilsocket") {
    repositories() {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20torvalds%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22torvalds%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositories()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20nelenkov%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22nelenkov%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositories()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20evilsocket%3A%20user(login%3A%20%22evilsocket%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositories()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

An example using graphql.js :

```
var users = [ "torvalds", "nelenkov", "evilsocket"];

var graph = graphql("https://api.github.com/graphql", {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  },
  asJSON: true
});

graph(`
  query {
    ${buildRepoCountFromUsers(users)}
  }
`, {}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

function buildRepoCountFromUsers(users){
  var query = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    query+=` ${users[i]} : user(login: ${users[i]}) {
      repositories() {
        totalCount
      }
    }`;
  }
  return query;
}
```

Note that I've chosen the user login as alias key here which works for the examples here but would not work if the login begins with a numeric character or if login contains hyphen. In that case you may use something like `user0`, `user1` etc... and get the field login for each user

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer was perfect!